# Mysql Not storing thai characters in longblob

Tags: mysql, encoding

My create table looks like below

```
 CREATE TABLE `mstr` (
  `ai_config_int_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `config_file_contents` longblob CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ai_config_int_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1235 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to store thai characters like "รด อล ล่า ร์" in config_file_contents column it does not store it. How to over come this issue

I even tried it through the value editor it says "Data could not be converted back to LATIN1: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input"

Comment: Are you sure the column is set to UTF8?

Comment: through what you try to store them? for example command line, pma, or your php script?